# Java: Check if a BufferedImage is BGR or RGB

Tags: java

I have an indexed image, and I'm trying to check if the `bufferedImage` has RGB or BGR color space.

```
ColorModel colorModel = bufferedImage.getColorModel();
if(colorModel instanceof IndexColorModel) {
   // check if the color space for the buffered image is BGR or RGB
}
```

I tried to use `bufferedImage.getType()`, unfortunately, `getType()` method return `TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED`. How can I check the color space for this kind of the `bufferedImage`?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to distinguished between RGB and BGR color space channels from unknown source, this is just an attribute have to be provided by user as an input. The image structure is just a three/four layers (depends if the image contains alpha layer or not) have an integer values in range [0-255], and determining color space from these pixels values will be hard to decide. I'm not sure if there is an algorithm that can solve this problem, but in all cases it will have an error ratio (depends on the image complexity). In my case, it will be safe to let the user to take the decision about the nature of the image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but judging from the API documentation:
(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED)

The IndexColorModel, which maps the index from your image to real colors, has a lot of methods to get red, green, or blue as arrays of int (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/IndexColorModel.html)
 Maybe you can use them.

It means that there might be no "RGB" or "BGR', what indexes in your buffered image are, is defined by the Indexed color model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_color)

Just a guess here, but if that can help.

Comment: Thanks Asoub, Indexed Image stored a useful information about the image in Palette which indexed palette contains a limited information about the image number color (4, 16, or 256). Assume we need to get the red color from unknown source image via Java API. e.g. colorModel.getRed(dataElements), and the Image color space is BGR. The image returns the blue color instead of getting the red color. where this behavior denotes to: "api lies on the developer"  ;)

Comment: I'm not sure if a researcher need to think about an algorithm to solve this problem. It will be hard to decide, and need much work to train his/her system - Ofcourse if he/she take a decision to go in AI. Or creating a histogram and studying the nature of the BGR vs RGB color spaces.

Comment: @Ahmad Where do you get your bufferedImage from ? If its loaded from another part of the program not using the default java awt loader (or whatever it is that creates a BufferedImage) like a custom one, then I guess you can't really know how the IndexedBuffer was made (just like you said ...). Where do you get it from ? Did you try the getRed(..[]) method and got the blue color array ?

Comment: sorry for late in replying, if you mean how I'm loading the indexed image, I'm using ImageIO.read(file) to load the images. I guess the secret in that image (maybe corrupted image?), I tried to download another image, and the getRed(..[]) is working fine.